# Intercepting hyperlink in MS Office Word JS API

Tags: jquery, http, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

In devs,

I am trying to add in functionality to my plug-in to do the following in JavaScript:

Listen to dynamically inputted hyperlinks (the user generates hyperlinks)

Upon click of a hyperlink, I want to configure the HTTP request to be sent using my program rather than opening a browser and then (hopefully) await data being sent back.

I've done some digging but, is this even possible? New to this, so sorry if it's a dumb question.

I've looked into using JQuery and VBA, but I'm not sure either of those are the answer.

I tried something like this:

```js
$(document).on("click",".appDetails", function() {
  var clickedBtnID = $(this).attr('id'); // or var clickedBtnID = this.id
  alert('you clicked on button #' + clickedBtnID);
});
```

Is there a way I can do this using the MS Word Office Add-In JS API?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, one can't stop opening the browser after clicking the hyperlink. If you don't want this, it's a good idea to remove the hyperlink and just use text. You can put the text in a ContentControl and catch the ContentControl.onEnter event to trigger what you want to do. But this functionality is in preview now, you can learn more using the following link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview#word-word-contentcontrol-onentered-member

Comment: I think you would have to look for "OnChanged" events and when a user creates a hyperlink, you'd need to manipulate it. Often people will store the HTTP URL in a comment and make the actual URL something like `#`. Do what they want w/ the code because the browser won't open I believe if the URL is not formatted correctly. Trying to intercept Hyperlinks is a bit of a hacky workaround. Its easier if you generate the links, but in essence thats what you are doing by watching for user generated HL's.